# Syntax in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am writing a trigger on mysql table. The code is following

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_on_product_option after update on db_name.table_name
FOR each row
BEGIN
    if new.isactive <> old.isactive then
            SET @inc=1;
            -- update statement on some table here
    else if new.lastupdatedts <> old.lastupdatedts then
        -- update statement on some table here
        set @t = 0;
    end if;
    end if;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

As you can see there are two `end if` at the end and surprisingly this trigger function is not throwing any errors even though there is an extra `end if;`  at the end. If I remove one `end if`, then it throws an error. unable to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ELSE IF, MySQL's syntax uses ELSEIF (without the space).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_on_product_option after update on db_name.table_name
FOR each row
BEGIN
    if new.isactive <> old.isactive then
           SET @inc=1;
            -- update statement on some table here
    elseif new.lastupdatedts <> old.lastupdatedts then
           -- update statement on some table here
        set @t = 0;
    end if;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Although you might be able to make it work with the space in ELSE IF by adding an additional END IF. By using the space, you effectively initiate a second IF statement, which must be closed independently of the first outer IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal(nested two `IF` stamements so both `IF` have to be closed):

```
if new.isactive <> old.isactive then
        SET @inc=1;
else if new.lastupdatedts <> old.lastupdatedts then
        set @t = 0;
     end if;
end if;
```

You probably wanted:

```
if new.isactive <> old.isactive then
        SET @inc=1;
elseif new.lastupdatedts <> old.lastupdatedts then
        SET @t = 0;
end if;
```

The difference is `ELSE IF` vs [`ELSEIF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use elseif (without space ) instead of else if. The reasion is when you use else if with space its consider else is use with starting if and you create new condition with if so its required to close with end if. So in your query required two end if.

DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER update_on_product_option after update on db_name.table_name FOR each row BEGIN if new.isactive <> old.isactive then SET @inc=1; -- update statement on some table here elseif new.lastupdatedts <> old.lastupdatedts then -- update statement on some table here set @t = 0; end if;  END; $$ DELIMITER ;